# SQL Server - Pivot of pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am new to SQL pivot queries and stuck in Pivot of Pivot result.

I have one table named "ExampleSales". I want to find the monthly (or even daily, weekly, Monthly, Yearly) employee and item wise Sales. Below is the example of table, sample data and first level pivot.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExampleSales](
    [SalesId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemCode] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeName] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [SalesDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ExampleSales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SalesId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample data:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ExampleSales] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[ExampleSales] ([SalesId], [ItemCode], [EmployeeName], [Amount],  [SalesDate]) VALUES (1, N'A1', N'Michel John', CAST(120.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0x07207D922A5ADF3C0B AS DateTime2))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ExampleSales] ([SalesId], [ItemCode], [EmployeeName], [Amount],  [SalesDate]) VALUES (2, N'A1', N'Mark Ven', CAST(50.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0x07D07748385AF33C0B AS DateTime2))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ExampleSales] ([SalesId], [ItemCode], [EmployeeName], [Amount],  [SalesDate]) VALUES (3, N'A2', N'Michel John', CAST(50.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0x07F05983465A023D0B AS DateTime2))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ExampleSales] ([SalesId], [ItemCode], [EmployeeName], [Amount],  [SalesDate]) VALUES (4, N'A2', N'Mark Ven', CAST(150.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0x073054DF505AFD3C0B AS DateTime2))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ExampleSales] ([SalesId], [ItemCode], [EmployeeName], [Amount],  [SalesDate]) VALUES (5, N'A3', N'Michel John', CAST(23.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0x0730AC235F5ADF3C0B AS DateTime2))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ExampleSales] ([SalesId], [ItemCode], [EmployeeName], [Amount],  [SalesDate]) VALUES (6, N'A3', N'Mark Ven', CAST(56.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0x07F02161695AF33C0B AS DateTime2))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ExampleSales] ([SalesId], [ItemCode], [EmployeeName], [Amount],  [SalesDate]) VALUES (7, N'A4', N'Michel John', CAST(54.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0x07C09BB2825A023D0B AS DateTime2))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ExampleSales] ([SalesId], [ItemCode], [EmployeeName], [Amount],  [SalesDate]) VALUES (8, N'A4', N'Mark Ven', CAST(100.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0x0750622E925ADB3C0B AS DateTime2))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ExampleSales] OFF
GO
```

First level pivot query

```
SELECT
DateName( month , DateAdd( month , DATEPART(m,SalesDate)  , 0 ) - 1 ) AS 'month',EmployeeName,[A1] ,[A2],[A3],[A4]
    FROM
        (SELECT 
                Salesid,SalesDate,EmployeeName,ItemCode
         FROM 
                ExampleSales
        ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
        COUNT(Salesid) 
        FOR ItemCode IN([A1] ,[A2],[A3],[A4])
    ) AS PivotTable
```

[Output of my first pivot query is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnV6o.png)

Now, I am stuck here. I want next level out as below.

[Need covert first pivot to next level pivot as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o44WG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic one:

Use as follows:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(concat(c.employeename,'(',c.itemcode,')')) 
            FROM examplesales c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'select * from
(select salesid,datename(month,salesdate) as mn,concat(employeename,''('',itemcode,'')'') as items from examplesales
) as S
pivot
(
count(salesid)
for items in  ('+@cols+') ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows:

```
select * from
(select salesid,datename(month,salesdate) as mn,concat(employeename,'(',itemcode,')') as items from examplesales
) as S
pivot
(
count(salesid)
for items in  ([Michel John(A1)],[Mark Ven(A1)],[Michel John(A2)],[Mark Ven(A2)],
                            [Michel John(A3)],[Mark Ven(A3)],[Michel John(A4)],[Mark Ven(A4)])
                            ) p
```

Result is :

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ranjana for very simple solution to my lengthy queries. Just wondering how to make this columns to dynamic.

Comment: Is below one is good way to make cols dynamic?

DECLARE @c AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @q  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @c = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(concat(employeename,'(',itemcode,')')) 
            FROM [dbo].[examplesales] c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

  SELECT @q = 
    'select * from
(select salesid,datename(month,salesdate) as mn,concat(employeename,''('',itemcode,'')'') as items from examplesales
) as S pivot ( count(salesid for items in  ('+@c+')) p'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @q

Comment: Hello @ChiragMehta I have commented another answer for dynamic one.